# Why a function assigns multiple values for each cell and running it alone for a single data frame it store single values?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I made a function that creates an ID number based on two columns from a data frame and the data frame name:

```
edit_dfs<-function(x){
      x["ID"]<-paste0(gsub("_.",replacement="",x),"_",x[["ua1"]],"_",x[["ua2"]])
      return(x)
    }
```

but when I run this function I get multiple values like:

```
test<-edit_dfs(I_df1)
> test["ID"]
# A tibble: 702 x 1
   ID                                                                                                                             
   <chr>                                                                                                                          
 1 "c(\"1\", \"1\", \"1\", ...continues
```

But, when I run the codes separately for each data frame it works as I want, example:

```
I_df["ID"]<-paste0(gsub("_.",replacement="","I_df"),"_",I_df[["ua1"]],"_",I_df[["ua2"]])
> I_df["ID"]
# A tibble: 702 x 1
   ID    
   <chr> 
 1 I_1_NA
 2 I_1_NA
 3 I_2_NA
Continues...and it is the result that I want
```

Can anyone explain me why is this happen and how to fix it? I want to do it in the form of a function to apply it for many data frames that I have.

Thank you

Comment: can you give us the output of `dput(head(I_df1))`?

Comment: In your function you use `gsub("_.",replacement="",x)` (`x` is a data.frame) and in your codes separately `gsub("_.",replacement="","I_df")` (`"I_df"` is a character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Juan Antonio Roldán Diaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9810485/juan-antonio-rold%C3%A1n-d%C3%ADaz) you are right, I can't believe I did not notice that.
Thank you very much for your help. I fixed the problem using `deparse(substitute(x))`

```
edit_dfs<-function(x){
  x["ID"]<-paste0(gsub("_.",replacement="",deparse(substitute(x))),"_",x[["ua1"]],"_",x[["ua2"]])
return(x)
    }
```